# eXist-db special characters in transformation and xmldb:store

Tags: xslt, xquery, exist-db

I've got a question concerning output escaping in eXist-db 4.5:

I'm using `transform:transform` (with `$serialization-options` = `method=text media-type=application/text`) and `xmldb:store` (with `$mime-type` = `text/plain`) to save the output of a XSL Transformation back to the Database. Inside my xslt-Stylesheet I'm using

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('Tom ', '&amp;', ' Peter')"/>
```

But the output that is saved back to eXist looks like `Tom $amp; Peter` instead of `Tom & Peter` like I was expecting.
When I specify `disable-output-escaping="yes"` eXist terminates with an error...

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('Tom ', '&amp;', ' Peter')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Using `transform:stream-transform` like suggested [here](http://exist.2174344.n4.nabble.com/disable-output-escaping-with-XSL-td4672397.html) doesn't work either because I need the output to be saved to a text-file.

How can I make sure that I can use `concat` and special characters like `&` in my XSL Transformation?

---

### Edit: Added Example

Say you've got an eXist collection named `temp` under `/db/apps/` with the following files in it:

#### `input.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testxml>
    <name>Peter</name>
</testxml>
```

#### `stylesheet.xsl`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Ampersand is not encoded: --> <xsl:value-of select="concat('Tom ', '&amp; ', testxml/name)"/> -->
    <!-- transformation fails: <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('Tom ', '&amp;', testxml/name)"/> -->
    <!-- Doesn't work obviously: <xsl:value-of select="concat('Tom ', '&', testxml/name)"/> -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And

#### `transformation.xq`

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare function local:xml2tex() as xs:string
{
let $mime-type := "text/plain"
let $stylesheet := doc("/db/apps/temp/stylesheet.xsl")
let $serializationoptions := "method=text media-type=application/text"
let $doc := doc("/db/apps/temp/input.xml")
let $filename := (replace(util:document-name($doc), "\.xml$", "") || ".tex")
let $transform := transform:transform(
    $doc,
    $stylesheet,
    (),
    (),
    $serializationoptions)
let $store := xmldb:store("/db/apps/temp", $filename, $transform, $mime-type)
return
$filename
};

local:xml2tex()
```

When you evaluate `transformation.xq` with the three contained `value-of select` options, you see that the working one produces a `*.tex` file with the content `Tom &amp; Peter` which is *not* what is intended (that would be `Tom & Peter`)

Comment: It would help greatly if you could post a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example demonstrating the phenomenon. Would that be possible? Then we can take a look at what would be necessary to fix the issue.

Comment: Hi @joewiz, I hope my example is sufficient!

Comment: It certainly was! I was able to reproduce your issue and get to the bottom of it. When you have the chance to take a look, please let me know if anything in my answer is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to eXist's function documentation for [`transform:transform()`](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/transform#transform.3), this function returns a `node()` (or an empty sequence). As a result, as much as you might try to force the result of your XSLT transformation to be a plain old string (as you did by supplying the `method=text` serialization parameter), the function will still return this string as a node - a text node.

When you pass a text node to the `xmldb:store()` function to store a text file (a .tex file in your case), serialization comes into play again, because the text node has to be serialized into the binary form that eXist uses for text files. The default serialization method is the XML method, which escapes strings when serializing text nodes.

To test this hypothesis, run the following query and examine the resulting files:

```
xmldb:store("/db", "01-text-node.txt", text { "Tom &amp; Peter" } ),
xmldb:store("/db", "02-string.txt", "Tom &amp; Peter" )
```

To avoid this problem and ensure the transformed value is stored using the text method, you should use one of several methods of deriving the text node's string value - here I'm applying these methods to your `$transform` variable:

1. Use the `cast as` operator: `$transform cast as xs:string`
2. Use the `fn:string()` function: `string($transform)` or `$transform/string()`.
3. Use the `fn:serialize()` function: `serialize($transform, map { "method": "text" } )`

**Update:** An issue reported in the comments below may lead the `transform:transform()` function to return more than one `node()`, which may lead solutions 1 and 2 above to lead to an unexpected cardinality error. A workaround is to use the `fn:string-join()` function. Solution 3 works without adjustment.

Comment: Thanks! Options 1 and 2 didn't work as we had more than one textnode after the transformation; got an error like `The actual cardinality for parameter 1 does not match the cardinality declared in the function's signature: string($arg as item()?) xs:string. Expected cardinality: zero or one, got 713.` Using the `fn:serialize()` function (option 3) worked, but we ended up using `string-join($transform)` which works as well! I'll accept your answer, perhaps you could add a fourth option?

Comment: Hmm, glad you found the string-join workaround, but I am confused how the result of transform:transform could be anything other than (zero-or-)one node. Is your code as written above really producing this result? If so, we may have an unknown bug in eXist. Any further info you can provide would be helpful!

Comment: The code of `transformation.xq` is exactly as we use it in eXist. Our `input.xml` and `stylesheet.xsl` however are obviously way more complex ;) If it would help you, I could send you those files!

Comment: That would be great. Could you please include them in a new issue at https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/new? Ideally, the test would demonstrate the `transform:transform()` function returning more than 1 `node()`.

Comment: sorry @joewiz I'll post an issue next week!